# Avoid static method creating instances with same value

Tags: java

My program should not be able to create new instances with values of same name but I don't know how to do. I imagined to put some if statments in the code but don't know how to implement it

```
public class Smurf {

    private String name;

    public static Smurf createSmurf(String name) {
        System.out.println("Creating " + name + " Smurf");
        return new Smurf(name);
    }

    private Smurf(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printName() {
        System.out.println("My name is " + name + " Smurf.");
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println(name + " Smurf is eating Smurfberries.");
    }

}
```

Comment: How would you do this in "real life"? You'd need to keep track of which Smurfs had been created, and if asked to create _Smurfette_ a second time, would "return" the one already created (or reject the request). You need to do something similar: track the names of objects that have been created (in an array/list/map etc.).

Comment: The equals method that is overridden from the Object class will be useful in your case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not going to do your homework for you, but some guidance:

- yes, when one Smurf instance has a **name**, then you need a non-static field in your class for that name
- but then: when you want to ensure that names are unique, then you need to *somehow* keep track of all known / used names

A very simple (error-prone, not real-world ready) solution: you could have a `private static final List<String> usedNames = new ArrayList<>()` within that class.

That list is **static**, so **all** instances of your class see the same list.

Now you could **check** in your creation method wether the name provided as argument is already in that list. If so, refuse to create the new Smurf. Otherwise, create the new Smurf, and add the new name to that list.

And in case you wonder "and why doesn't that work in the real world": because A) it is a bad design that the Smurf class keeps track of *all* Smurf names and B) maybe Gargamel eats `Careless Smurf` at some point. Then you would need additional code to delete that name from the list. Or, you couldn't use the name again when `Careless Smurf` wants to re-spawn. And so on.

Note: no smurfs were hurt during the writing of this answer though.

Comment: fabulous non-code answer, imho. this is what SO is all about at times.

Answer (score 1):

Probably keep your smurfs in a Map like this:

```
private static final Map<String, Smurf> smurfs = new HashMap<>();
```

And then add all new smurfs to that Map and return the original smurf from the map if it already exists:

```
public static Smurf createSmurf(String name) {
    Smurf newSmurf = null;
    if(smurfs.containsKey(name)) {
        System.out.println("Smurf " name + " already exists.")
        newSmurf = smurfs.get(name);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Creating " + name + " Smurf");
        newSmurf = new Smurf(name);
        smurfs.put(name, newSmurf);
    }
    return newSmurf;
}
```

Be aware that this is neither threadsafe nor good design, but it'll do what you want.

Comment: You forget to put the newly created Smurf into the map, so you'll always create a new one. Also, we have `computeIfAbsent` now, so `return map.computeIfAbsent(name, Smurf::new)`.

Comment: Silly me. Fixed that ;-) ```computeIfAbsent``` is neat, but I think the old fashioned way is easier to read for beginners.

Comment: Note that your method name is lying. It says *create*. But it doesnt necessarily create a new Smurf. Names should say what the thing named does, and the thing should do what the name says.

Comment: Also note: when you rename that method, consider to include `alsoCreatePotentialMemoryLeak()`... because depending on how things get used, that is the big problem with this approach ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I want to thanks all of you for your answers, most of all of GhostCat for helping the most.
In the end I just finished creating an array list and put the smurfs in it and do the checks.

I have to so much more to learn and maybe you're going to see another question soon

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. You Can Check this out.
There are Possibilities of Correction.

```
public class Smurf {

private String name;
private static final List<String> usedName = new ArrayList<>();

public static Smurf createSmurf(String name) {
    if (usedName.contains(name)){
        System.out.println("Cannot create "+name + " Smurf");
        return null;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Creating " + name + " Smurf");
        return new Smurf(name);
    }
}

private Smurf(String name) {
    if (usedName.contains(name)){
        return;
    }
    this.name = name;
    usedName.add(name);
}


public void printName() {
    System.out.println("My name is " + name + " Smurf.");
}
public void eat() {
    System.out.println(name + " Smurf is eating Smurfberries.");
}
}
```